# pass image url from variable into css

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am calling a product image url from my database, and in the front end page, I have some css which styles the image on the page. however, I need to pass the url of the product image into the css which specifies the url of the image...

my css:

```
  .product-image .bg{
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521572163474-6864f9cf17ab?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dHNoaXJ0fGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60  ');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
}
```

product page which shows the background image

```
<div class="product group">
<div class="col-1-2 product-image">
```

where product-image is put in the div, it renders the product image. how can I pass this url `<%= data[I].IMAGE_URL %>` into the css? so instead of having ->

`background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521572163474-6864f9cf17ab?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dHNoaXJ0fGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60');` ->

I would have `background-image: url('<%= data[I].IMAGE_URL');`

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done. As long as you put that on an .aspx, or any other page rendered on the server, page you'll be good. Just change it to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```css
product-image .bg {
    background-image: url("<%=someImageURL%>");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense... I hardcoded the value of the imageURL into a variable in a loop on the backend, then passed the variable to the front end and used it like you said... thanks!